# Angularjs hide table column

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show, ng-hide

I am again working with this table and running into problems.  Standard table using ng-repeat and binding data with ng-bind.  I have a drop down that has All/Open/Posted. It sets disabledToggle to True or False.  So what I would like is when it is set to false the received date column is hidden.  Inversely when it is True then the received date to be visible.

I've placed the ng-hide on the header and it only removed the header not the column data.  I've also place the ng-hide on the table cell.  All this did was shift the table data over one cell.  So the data wouldnt line up correctly.

```
         <table id="tblItemList" class="table table-responsive table-hover table-striped" oci.fixed-header infinite-scroll="vm.scrollItems()" infinite-scroll-distance="1" infinite-scroll-parent="true">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                 <th class="cursorptr" style="width:15%">
                     <span>Invoice Date</span>
                 </th>
                 <th ng-hide="!order.disabledToggle">
                     <span>
                          <span>Received Date</span>
                     </span>
                 </th>
                 <th class="cursorptr" style="width:15%">
                     <span>
                          <span>Invoice number </span>
                     </span>
                  </th>
                  <th class="cursorptr" style="width:10%">
                     <span>
                          <span>Order Number</span>
                     </span>
                  </th>
                  <th style="width:6%">
                     <span>
                          <span>LInes </span>
                     </span>
                  </th>
                  <th style="width:10%">
                     <span>
                         </span>
                  </th>
                 <th style="width:10%">
                     <span>Tracking</span>
                  </th>
                  <th style="width:10%">
                     <span>Action</span>
                   </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
             <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="order in vm.orders track by $index"  ng-dblclick="vm.EditInvoiceModal(order)" style="cursor:pointer" >                                            
                   <td ng-bind="(order.dtInvoiced | date:'MM/dd/yyyy' )"> </td> 
                   <td ng-bind="(order.dtReceived | date:'MM/dd/yyyy' )" ng-hide="!order.disabledToggle"></td>
                   <td ng-bind="order.invoiceNumber"></td>
                   <td ng-bind="order.invoiceItems.mdbsPoNumber"></td>
                   <td align="center" ng-bind="order.lines"></td>
                   <td ng-bind="(order.total | number:2)"></td>
                   <td align="center" ng-bind="order.carrier"></td>                                                
                   <td>
                       <a ng-click="vm.EditInvoiceModal(order)"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-2x"></i></a>                                                    
                       <a ng-click="order.disabledToggle || vm.commitOrder(order)" ></a>

                  </tr>
               </tbody>
```

Comment: did you try `ng-hide` on both (head and body) and still got error/misalignment?

Comment: Yes that was my first train of thought

Comment: can you create a plnkr or something? it should be working if you do it for head and body. for head i dont see where the `order` comes from.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?